# Show edit summary in reopen review

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, vote-to-reopen, edit-summary

When reviewing reopen votes triggered by an edit, the Revision tab should show the edit summary:

[image: mock up]

Often, there's valuable context that the edit summary explains which a reviewer may not understand if unfamiliar with the particulars of the question.

As an example, twice I've edited questions (not mine) that were closed as unclear, by clarifying the question and further explaining in the summary that the question was actually clear to those familiar with the obscure tag. In the end I had to ask moderators to reopen because the reviewers never saw my summary! *In both cases, the question was subsequently answered and accepted.*

Comment: It's funny that I only got four upvotes before this was status-completed. Everything else came after. So much for voting on feature requests to be implemented ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good idea - the revision summary will now be displayed.

Edit:  Because the Revision tab is a better view into what changed since closure, the next build will display that Revision tab when the task loads.

Comment: Looks like the summary is broken [for rollbacks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245245/i-just-got-a-really-weird-reopen-review-about-a-rollback-to-e6f666a5-1009-4456)?