# I just got a really weird Reopen review about a rollback to [e6f666a5-1009-4456-b217-6ad0a889d0f6]

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-reopen, rollbacks, edit-summary

I just got [this review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/13314) which appears to be a little broken and buggy:

[image: - 20 mins ago - rollback to {gibberish}. No changes to display.]

Take note of the edit summary featured in this review - it's bugged out. In the post's revision history, it says "Rollback to Revision 5" instead.

In case it's relevant to the bug, I performed the rollback presently featured in the review. The edit I rolled back was probably the one that put it in the reopen queue.

Comment: Not really a bug, that's the raw text which is saved automatically as the edit summary in case of rollback. In the revisions list it's being parsed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard seems like it should get parsed here too, or really anywhere it's presented to a human being.

Comment: Fair enough, but keep in mind that until recently, there [wasn't edit summary at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231059/show-edit-summary-in-reopen-review?rq=1).

Comment: I've reproduced that just recently, so it's still a bug/feature. It's be nice to see it changed.